# C finding the lesser difference between two stacks

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

If i have two `stacks`, which i have to put elements that come from an `array`, and i have to find a recursive way to put elements that obey the rule of finding the lesser difference between the sum of the two stacks...

Like this:

```
values[5] ={1,2,3,4,5}

Stack1 = 4,3

Stack2 = 5,2,1

or 

Stack2 = 4,3

Stack1 = 5,2,1
Difference = between 1 and 2  = 1
```

Can you help me finding a way to do this recursively? or at least understanding how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean the way to minimize the difference between two stacks? Do the order of putting element into stack is the same order as in the array?

Comment: Yea so that the difference between two arrays is 0 or near 0 and the order doesn't matter since its a recursive problem that tries all solutions ...

Answer (score 4):

This is basically the **[partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)** which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

You are trying to split thew array to two subsets (stacks in your case, does not matter) such that their sum is equal in best case, or as closest as possible to it.

**There is no known polynomial solution to it**, but if the numbers are fairly small integers - there is a nice [dynamic programming solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_algorithm) to solve it quickly.

A greedy approach (putting the highest element in the stack with the lower sum, and repeat) is a an approximation that at worst case will be `|SUM|/2` worse than optimal solution.

**EDIT**: the Dynamic programming approach is basically recursive by nature:

```
base:
f(0,i) = true
f(x,0) = false    (x > 0)
step:
f(x,i) = f(x-arr[i],i-1) OR f(x,i-1)
```

Invoke with `f(SUM/2,n)` to find if there is optimal solution.

Now, think:

1. How from this you can find 'closest' solution if `f(SUM/2,n) =
   false`?
2. How you can modify this solution to also give you the indices of the desired solution, and not only a boolean answer?

**Note:**

- Another recursive approach would be to check for all possible subsets
  of the array (there are 2^n of those), and choose the one that
  minimizes the difference to `|SUM|/2`

Comment: OP asks to do it recursively, so the point of the question at hand is probably practicing programming techniques rather than reducing the computational complexity.

Comment: @barakmanos Dynamic programming is a recursion by nature, you build it bottom-up as optimization, but it has a recursive approach behind it.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, dynamic programming is iterative by nature (take the solution to LCS, for example).

Comment: @barakmanos bottom-up DP is done by iteration for reasons of efficiency, but it is implementing a recursive approach of splitting the problem to smaller sub-probmlems, calculating for each smaller subproblem, and do the extra step to calculate for the current larger problem. This is the exact same idea of a recursive solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you give me some pseudo code or something near to real code so i can see if im close to the solution using only recursion and not DP?

Comment: @exceltior The definition of `f(x,i)` is almost a pseudo code already - just put the two base clauses in if statements and the step as the else. What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I tried to do the recursive function a follows: where it should give the real difference between stackA and stackB based on your solution but it gives `0.00` where it should give `0.09` with the following input:
`4
1.21
1.53
1.80
2.03
`
`starts with SUM/2 in x and n in i`




`//Function: 
`
`public static float dp(float value,int i,float v[]){
  if(value == 0){
   return 0;
  }
  if(i == 0){
   return value;
  }
  return dp(value-v[i],i-1,v);
 }`

Comment: @exceltior The DP solution I suggested is fit for integers. You can still use it if you treat 1.21 as 121, 1.80 as 180, .... An alternative is the brute force I suggested as well - just create all subsets and choose the best out of them. Hope it makes sense.